# sum of values giving NaN

Tags: javascript

We were using below code to fetch commission from Database and displaying in column.

```
$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT commission1 FROM tbl_users where userID=:uid"); 
$stmt->execute(array(":uid" => $_SESSION['userSession'])); // this line
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$commission =  $row['commission1'] ;
```

[image]

We were using below code to add those commissions & give value of Total commission :

```
var commission=0;
for (var i = 0; i < mygrid.dataset.data.length; i++) {
console.log(mygrid.dataset.data[i]);
if(mygrid.dataset.data[i][10] != "Returned" && mygrid.dataset.data[i][10] != "Cancelled"){
commission=commission+parseInt(mygrid.dataset.data[i][8]);
}
console.log(commission);
}
$(".delete_grid").append(" , Total commission : "+commission);
```

[image]

But the issue was **it was fetching wrong commission from Database**, so we replaced to below code to fetch correct commission :

[image]

```
$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT commission1 FROM tbl_users where userID=:uid  "); //I assume user_id is field of database in tbl_user table
$stmt->execute(array(":uid" => $productdetail->getDesignerID() )); // this line
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$commission =  $row['commission1'] ;
```

Now issue is Total commission is showing "NaN"

[image]

After researching , i got i need to **initialize** some variable, but i am new to javascript & i am not getting what value i need to initialize in my case.

**update**

i removed some `html form` code , after i followed Rajesh's sugestion : `console.log(mygrid.dataset.data[i][8])` i got error in console :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '8' of undefined at line 436

<form>
Search:

<select id="f_value2">
    <option value="entity_id">Order Id</option>
</select>


<input type="text" onkeyup="doFilter()" value="" id="f_value1" >
<input type="reset" value="Reset" onClick="window.location.reload()"> // line 436
</form>
```

**update 2**

Comment: Please log `console.log(mygrid.dataset.data[i][8])` and share what its value is

Comment: after i used your code as `$(".delete_grid").append("Number of rows : "+mygrid.dataset.getSize());
console.log(mygrid.dataset.data[i][8]);`  it gave `blank` instead of `Total commission : NaN`

Comment: What did you see in `console`?

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '8' of undefined
    at `  line `446` , but there is no code in line `446`

Comment: One of your `mygrid.dataset.data[i][8]` does not contain a number. You have to doublecheck the data you get in the Javascript from PHP (check on JS side)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132700/discussion-on-question-by-user5348fh8y5-sum-of-values-giving-nan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

credits : [Rajesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3783478/rajesh)

```
commission = commission + (parseInt(mygrid.dataset.data[i][8]) || 0)
```